# How to toggle class for font awesome icons with pure javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I am trying to learn javascript and trying to toggle between the empty circle icon and the circle with check mark when the icon is clicked. However, it does not seem to be working.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/0c7c27ff53.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <i class="far fa-circle" id="toggle"></i>
 <script>
    document.addEventListener('click', (event) =>{
        if(event.target.id == 'toggle'){
            document.getElementById('toggle').classList.toggle("fas fa-check-circle");
        }
    });
 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you think you already got that `event.target` (Element!) than there's not need to go again to query the entire DOM in search for some Element you already have! (PS: `event.target`) :)

Comment: Part of the problem as well, is that you aren't removing the original class `far fa-circle`

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it's more helpful to define your element **default** CSS and than use a **`is-*`** class modifier - than doing funky stuff with *fas* classes. Take a look:

```js
const EL_tog = document.querySelector('#toggle');

EL_tog.addEventListener('click', () => {
    EL_tog.classList.toggle("is-active");
});
```

```css
#toggle:before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  content: "\f111";
  font-style: normal;
}

#toggle.is-active:before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  content: "\f058";
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css">

<i id="toggle"></i>
```

*Tomorrow*, even if you decide to use another icons-set, you don't need to change the HTML, just your CSS. Which is after all - all what's about.

If you wonder where I got that hex values for CSS `content:` like `\f111` - not a [big deal](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css)

Comment: they are also available here: https://fontawesome.com/icons/check-circle?style=solid and you need to add font-weight:900 for the last icon because it's the solid version not the regular one

Answer (score 1):

An idea is to use the stacking icons and you can deal with only one class:

```js
var icon = document.getElementById('toggle');

icon.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  icon.querySelector(':last-child').classList.toggle("fa-check-circle");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/0c7c27ff53.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<span class="fa-stack fa-2x" id="toggle">
  <i class="far fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-stack-2x"></i> <!-- OR "far" for the other version -->
</span>
```

Related: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/stacking-icons

Comment: Nice example! Just - in that case you're pretty much stuck with fas internals which are odd at best (regarding HTML markup) ;)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan we can still consider better selector ;)

Answer (score 1):

We can solve this using vanilla JavaScript.

Just add an `onclick` listener to the `toggle` element. Then replace the class `fa-circle` with `fa-check-circle`.

```js
const circle = 'fa-circle'
const check = 'fa-check-circle'
const toggler = document.getElementById('toggle')
toggle.onclick = () => {
  toggler.classList.toggle(circle)
  toggler.classList.toggle(check)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/0c7c27ff53.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<i id="toggle" class="far fa-circle"></i>
```

Another way is using `css` just define a new class (i.e. `active`) with the pseudo attribute `before` like this:

```css
#toggle.active::before {
  content: '\f058';
}
```

Now, we add an `onclick` event to the `toggle` element to add or remove the `active` class:

```js
toggle.onclick = () => {
  toggler.classList.toggle('active')
}
```

```js
const toggler = document.getElementById('toggle')
toggle.onclick = () => {
  toggler.classList.toggle('active')
}
```

```css
#toggle.active::before {
  content: '\f058';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/0c7c27ff53.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<i id="toggle" class="far fa-circle"></i>
```